# Type assertion in go

Tags: go, interface, type-assertion

I have this code snippet:

```
if (reflect.TypeOf(device).String() == "*types.VirtualDisk") {
    disk := device.(types.VirtualDisk)
    fmt.Printf("%v - %v \n", "capacityInKB", disk.CapacityInKB)
}
```

to which I get:

> impossible type assertion:    types.VirtualDisk does not implement
>   types.BaseVirtualDevice (GetVirtualDevice method has pointer receiver)

But If I modify it to

```
if (reflect.TypeOf(device).String() == "*types.VirtualDisk") {
    //disk := device.(types.VirtualDisk)
    fmt.Printf("%v - %v \n", "capacityInKB", device)//disk.CapacityInKB)
}
```

It works and prints all the properties of the object. How am I suppose to convert this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error hints that the type you want to type assert is `*types.VirtualDisk` and not `types.VirtualDisk`.

Also that reflection trick you're trying to do is completely unnecessary, as there is a [special form of the type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) which reports whether the assertion holds.

See this example:

```
if disk, ok := device.(*types.VirtualDisk); ok {
    // Type assertion holds, disk is of type *types.VirtualDisk
    // You may use it so
}
```

Comment: @mario-stoilov, I concur: you should abstrain from using the `reflect` package as much as you can. Using it most of the time signalizes code smell as the only case where it's really called for is when you work with (user-supplied) types you completely know nothing about beforehand, and have to inspect their structure at runtime. The `encoding/xml` and `encoding/json` packages are two very good examples.